# Facebook API: (SDK Version 3) Authenticate and Post to Page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've just downloaded the Facebook SDK Version 3 and there are some significant changes. My goal is to get everything working so a user can be authenticated, then when they add a new page (different screen) they can post to that page. Please take a look at my code and let me know how it can be fixed! Currently, the access_token and secret aren't being retrieved, among other things

authenticate.php:
http://pastebin.com/y0Rdmmbs

add_page.php: http://pastebin.com/17ExQzCB

If you have better code to use, rather than the code shown in those files, that's totally fine with me. At this point I just want it to work! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your multitude of `die` statements make me want to cry. You might want to check out [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for tips on improving your code.

Comment: The code is being improved as we speak, hopefully, but lots of code that makes you want to cry still runs fine. I'd appreciate constructive help.

Comment: You asked for an opinion on your code, and I gave you mine. There's a *lot* of bad code that runs, but that doesn't mean it's correct. Take time to think about gracefully handling errors and separating business logic from your output

Comment: Sorry, I've cleared up the original post, I wanted to figure out why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write your code for you, but I will point you in the right direction.

Facebook developer documentation is by no means a well maintained resource, but their sections on Authentication and the PHP SDK are perfectly fine for your needs. On the authentication page, they even have an example of how to use the PHP SDK to authenticate.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/